# Magento custom module click view get the product details from quote id

Tags: magento-1.9

how to get the **product details from quote id**, click on view in custom module 
magento.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Quote ID as Parameter in your view url and from that Quote ID you can get the Product ID

```
$quoteId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quote_id');
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
}
```

Comment: How to pass the quite id for this custom module

Comment: $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    =>  Mage::helper('quotation')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '100',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'    => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(

Comment: array(
                        'caption'   => Mage::helper('quotation')->__('View'),
                        'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                        'field'     => 'id'
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));

Comment: 2nd post is the continuation of code